# Mockito: how to return mocked class object in method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I want to write unit tests for the following class. The class has only `execute` method and it requires 3 parameters so I can provide those params with mocks/fakes. However, it has also `SiteInfo.filter` call inside method so I should also mock this object.

I have this error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:
> Unfinished stubbing detected here:

```java
public static class SiteResponseExecutor
{
  public SiteResourseExecute execute(final String url,
                                     final SiteResponse response,
                                     final Map<String, String> responseData)
  {
    final String responseType = responseData.get(type);
    final SiteInfo siteInfo = SiteInfo.filter(responseType);

    if (siteInfo.getType() != null)
    {
      ....

      if (siteInfo.getEncode() != null && siteInfo.getType().startsWith("image"))
      {
        ...
      }
    }
    else if (responseData.get(HttpClient.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH) != null)
    {
      ...
    }


    return new SiteResourseExecute(
        siteInfo.getType(), siteInfo.getEncode(),
        response.getResponseStatus(), getPharese(response.getStatus()),
        responseData, response.getInputStream());
  }
}
```

`filter` is

```java
public static SiteInfo filter(final String type)
{
  final SiteInfo siteInfo = new SiteInfo();

  ...
  return siteInfo;
}
```

When I try to mock the methods that are used by the `execute` method first two method returns primitives but the last one is returning class instance so I want to make it returns already mocked object.

```java
// creating mock object to pass it when filter() method is called
final SiteInfo mockSiteInfo = Mockito.mock(SiteInfo.class);
mockSiteInfo.setType("application/octet-stream");
mockSiteInfo.setEncoding("gzip, deflate");

// first two when are OK, but the last one gives UnfinishedStubbingException
final SiteInfo siteInfo = Mockito.mock(SiteInfo.class);
Mockito.when(siteInfo.getType()).thenReturn("type1");
Mockito.when(siteInfo.getEncode()).thenReturn("type2");
doReturn(mockSiteInfo).when(SiteInfo).filter("type1");
```

How can I return the mocked object for this method call?

Comment: You are attempting to mock a static method `SiteInfo.filter` with `doReturn / when`. Mockito does support mocking statics (since 3.4.0) but you need to use `mockStatic`. Ideally avoid it by injecting the dependency. This approach will be much more testable.

Comment: @sprinter I stuck to an older version, what should I do?

Comment: 1. Create a `SiteInfoProvider` class with non-static `filter` method. 2. Pass an instance of `SiteInfoProvider` either to constructor of `SiteResponseExecutor` or to `execute` method itself. If `SiteInfoProvider` is stateless, passing it to constructor would be a common approach.

Comment: @MesutGUNES exactly what @Lesiak said (which is what I meant by injecting the dependency). Note carefully the point that the `filter` method should not be static.